# Using Mmap first character is wrong

Tags: c, mmap

Using Mmap I want to change the contents of file from Hello,world! to Jello, world!

The input file is Hello.txt    which is 1 line   Hello,world!
The output is usually `ello,world!
The output should be Jello,world!
to run the program  pgm.exe hello.txt 1

the critical lines of code are  at end of program  (maybe something is is critical and I just dont know it)

thank you for your help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
int     fd, changes, i  ;
struct stat buf;
char        *the_file,
    *starting_string = "Jello,world!";

if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Usage: %s file_name #_of_changes\n", *argv);
    exit(1);
}

if ((changes = atoi(argv[2])) < 1) {
    printf("#_of_changes < 1\n");
    exit(1);
}

if ((fd = open(argv[1], O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0666)) < 0) {
    printf("open error on file %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}

//write(fd, starting_string, strlen(starting_string));

/* Obtain size of file to be mapped */
if (fstat(fd, &buf) < 0) {
    printf("fstat error on file %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
}

/* Establish the mapping */
if ((the_file = mmap(0, (size_t)buf.st_size, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE,
    MAP_SHARED, fd, 0)) == (caddr_t)-1){
    printf("mmap failure\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("The file orginally contains:\n %s \n", the_file);

*(the_file) = "Jello,world!"; 

printf("The file now contains:\n %s \n", the_file);

exit(0);


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line

```
*(the_file) = "Jello,world!";
```

Assigns the truncated value of the address of `"Jello,world!"` to the first character in your file.

To assign the single character `'J'` to that address, this works:

```
*(the_file) = 'J';
```

Also, this line:

```
printf("The file orginally contains:\n %s \n", the_file);
```

is a SEGV waiting to happen.  There's no guarantee your file contains a NUL-terminated string.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot copy arrays by direct assignment.

use `memcpy()`

If both source and target were nil terminated character arrays (not true in this case), you can use `strcpy(), strncpy()` or (bsd only) `strlcpy()`.